# Is there a way to make an even more abstract code from this?

Tags: c++

I have the following problem: I have a Data class which stores strings in a vector, and two classes derived from it: Team and Player. I want to make a table of indices so to say with a map which stores integers associated to strings meaning that eg. the ID of the player is stored on the 0th position of the vector. Here is the code (not in details):

```
class Data{
protected:
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    //etc.
};

class Player:public Data{
    static std::map<std::string, int> table_of_indices;
public:
    std::string operator[](const std::string& str) {return data[table_of_indices[str]];}
};

class Team:public Data{
    static std::map<std::string, int> table_of_indices;
public:
    std::string operator[](const std::string& str) {return data[table_of_indices[str]];}
};
```

The problem is that both derived classes look exactly alike hower the content of their maps are different. However, is there a way to somehow include the element access operator and the table of indices in the Data class and then initialize the maps for the Player and Team classes separately?

Comment: @KonradRudolph as an answer ;)

Comment: I'm not sure what the difficulty is, just put the `map` and `operator[]` in `Data`, and fill them with their own `setAttribute` or whatever function.

Comment: You guys notice that the map is `static`?

Comment: That doesn't work because the table_of_indices variable is different for Player and Team.

Comment: @leemes Ooops ! No we didn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all this is not good objective programming. You should ask yourself a question: "Is player a data?" and "Is team a data?". The answer is no, so player and team shouldn't derive from `Data`.

You should extend your `Data` class with this additional elements and then use it inside `Player` and `Team`.

Your new `Data` class should look similar to:

```
class Data{
    std::vector<std::string> data;
    std::map<std::string, int> table_of indices;
    //etc.
    public:
        std::string operator[](const std::string& str) {return data[table_of_indices[str]];}
};
```

Then you can initialize it with different `map` for different usage.

In order to avoid cloning whole `map` you can use pointer instead of map:

```
std::map<std::string, int>* table_of indices;
```

And then in `Data` constructor you can set the pointer:

```
public Data(std::map<std::string, int>* table_of_indices) {
    this.table_of indices = table_of_indices;
}
```

Now inside `Player` you can still have your static map. Additionaly you should add `Data` instance.

```
class Player {
       static std::map<std::string, int> table_of indices;
       Data *player_data;
   public:
       std::string operator[](const std::string& str) {return *player_data[str];}
       Player() { player_data = new Data(&Player::table_of_indices); }
       ~Player() { delete player_data; }
};
```

Comment: But using your method what's the point in placing a `table_of_indices` inside the data structure? To me it seems like that in this case it has no actual purpose there.

Comment: @user3237992 I tried to make it as similar to original solution as possible. Player and Team can have static map which can be changed as you wish. Data has pointer to such map, so it can work with it.

Answer (score 3):

That's a job for [CRTP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) !

```
template <class Tderived>
struct DataIndexer : Data {
    friend struct Tderived;

    std::string const &operator [] (const std::string& str) const {
        return data[table_of_indices[str]];
    }

private:
    DataIndexer() {}

    static std::map<std::string, int> table_of_indices;
};
```

Now you can make `Player` inherit from `DataIndexer<Player>`, and that new instanciation will have its own static members.